# Merge missing disk partition on a Macbook

Tags: macos, command-line, partition, apfs, dual-boot

I tried to install a Linux distro on a partition in my macbook, but it didn't go well so i want that partition to merge it to my main partition of the OS, but in the disk utility doesn't appear. If i run the `diskutil list` command this is what I got:

```
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         208.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨⁩                        525.3 MB   disk0s3
   4:           Linux Filesystem ⁨⁩                        31.5 GB    disk0s4
   5:                 Linux Swap ⁨⁩                        4.0 GB     disk0s5
   6:           Linux Filesystem ⁨⁩                        6.0 GB     disk0s6
```

If I run the command `gpt -rf show disk0` I get this:

```
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: error: bogus map
gpt show: unable to open device ‘disk0’: no such file or directory
```

I want to merge the partition 4, 5 and 6 to the APFS disk1.

Is this possible?

Comment: Before you do **anything** do a thorough backup.

Comment: Alexandru: Can you boot to macOS Recovery and post the output from the command `gpt -rf show disk0`?

Answer (score 1):

Linux filesystem partitions may not not appear in the Disk Utility application. I would not recommend using the Disk Utility or `diskutil` command to remove Linux filesystem or swap partitions. Usually, attempting leads to an unbootable macOS.

I would recommend the following two ways to remove linux partitions.

- If your Linux installer flash drive has a bootable live version, then boot to this live version. Most Linux versions include the `gdisk` command. Use this command to remove the linux partitions.
- Boot to macOS Recovery. Basically restart the Mac and hold down the command(⌘)-R key combination. Once booted, open a Terminal application window and use the

  ```
   gpt -f remove -i N disk0
  ```

  command to remove each Linux partition. You need to replace `N` with the correct partition index. You can use the

  ```
   gpt -rf show disk0
  ```

  command to list the partitions. The Linux partitions have the following partition GUID type values.

  ```
   Linux Filesystem          0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
   Linux LVM                 E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928
   Linux Swap                0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
  ```